# unable to bind keypress in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, key-bindings, tkinter-canvas

I looked through about a dozen posts about Tkinter, binding keypress events, and canvas widgets, but none of the solutions I read changed anything in my program. The GUI currently works with Button-1 as the event, but I need it to be operable from a keyboard. I tried using various keys and letters of the alphabet. I've also tried self.c.focus_set(), which didn't work when I tried binding the event to the canvas or to the frame. Here's my code:

```
from Tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.parent = master
        frame = Frame(master)
        screen_width, screen_height = master.winfo_screenwidth(), master.winfo_screenheight()
        frame.configure(background='black')
        frame.place(x=0,y=0,width=screen_width,height=screen_height)
        master.overrideredirect(1)


        h = .8*screen_height
        self.c = Canvas(frame, width=h, height=h, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, bg='black')
        self.c.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
        radius = 10
        self.c.update_idletasks()

        hCanvas = (self.c.winfo_height())
        offset = int(float(.4*hCanvas))
        self.c.create_oval(hCanvas/2-radius, hCanvas/2-radius, hCanvas/2+radius, hCanvas/2+radius, fill='white', outline='white')

        self.c.focus_set()
        self.c.update_idletasks()
        self.c.bind('<Key>', lambda event, arg=[radius]: self.create_stim(event, arg))

    def create_stim(self, event, args):
        print('create stim')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    app=App(root)

    root.update()
    root.mainloop()
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

- Edited to reflect changes suggested by martineau.

Currently, when I run the program this way, I am no longer in fullscreen, I cannot click on the window to select it, and I get the error noise every time I hit a key on the keyboard. If I put root.attributes('-fullscreen', True) after app=App(root), then I get the GUI in fullscreen and I can click on it, and again get the error noise every time a key is pressed.
Is it possible there is a problem with the version of python (2.7.10) running on my computer (MacBook Pro, running on OS X Yosemite, 10.10.4)? Should I download python 3?

Comment: Have you tried binding it to the root object with `master.bind('<Space>', lambda...`?

Comment: What does it do when you claim it doesn't work? Does it throw an error? If so, what error?

Comment: Can't run the code in your question: `_tkinter.TclError: can't set fullscreen attribute for ".": override-redirect flag is set` Also there's no def for `create_image()`.

Comment: @BryanOakley I don't get any errors when I run the GUI, but nothing happens when I press a key. When I ran it with '<Button-1>', I was able to click on the canvas and get to the next screen.

Comment: @martineau create_image is a function I have in another file, sorry I didn't make that clear. It returns a dictionary, where values are 2D lists of 0's and 1's. The GUI is supposed to cycle through movies of the images, which are plotted like a checkerboard on the canvas. I haven't run into any problems with overrideredirect and fullscreen when I was working with the event as '<Button-1>'

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I tried binding to the root, and that didn't work either

Comment: I moved the `root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)` to right after the `root = Tk()` to get rid of the `_tkinter.TclError`. To avoid the lack of a `create_image` function, I changed `create_stim()` to just `print('create_stim() called')` followed by a `return`. After doing all that, whenever I press a key `create_stim() called` is printed. In other words, I cannot replicate your binding keypress event problem.

Comment: Suggest you read _and follow_ the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) help article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a limitation of Tkinter on OSX. When you call  `master.overrideredirect(1)`, it seems to turn off the ability for tkinter to process keyboard events. If you omit the call to `overrideredirect` your code will start to work.